# How does this create an error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

I have a jquery/ajax website at [tarh33ls.com](http://tarh33ls.com)
For some reason, in firefox, i get the following error:

> uncaught exception: [Exception...
>   "Component returned failure code:
>   0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)
>   [nsIDOMLocation.href]"  nsresult:
>   "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" 
>   location: "JS frame ::
>   http://tarh33ls.com/ ::  ::
>   line 26"  data: no]
>
> Line 0

but line 26 is:

```
if (location.href.indexOf("#")==-1) {location.href="http://tarh33ls.com/#";}
```

How would that generate an error?

Comment: very weird ... do a check before that line something like:

console.log(location.href);
perhaps location.href is still undefined somehow ...

this seems to work fine on GC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the error happens, but it seems this fixes it:

Move the `if (location.href.indexOf("#") == -1` code inside the `$(document).ready` block (at the top of it), like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (location.href.indexOf("#") == -1) {
        location.href="http://tarh33ls.com/#";
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({
...etc
```

Comment: It's generally a good idea when using jQuery to include init code in inside `$(document).ready`, to prevent code from running on an incomplete page.

Comment: what do you mean? also, i would vote up your answer, but i don't have enough rep :P

Comment: @tarH33ls If you have js running outside of it, it runs as the browser sees it. So for example you may have js that changes some html elements that, in the source code, are below the js. The code will try to run but won't find the HTML. Using ready means the page will load completely before running your js. (I hope I'm clear.. maybe the [jQuery page on `ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) explains it better than me)

Comment: you are right , i ran into some problems...by not placing some inline code in document.ready , one script was executing before...other script , i fixed it by placing in document.ready, thaks for your explanation

Comment: oh, ok thanks i just misunderstood you at first, i thought you were saying that i had to initialize jQuery